# How can I call a JS function within my html.erb and passing as argument a ruby variable?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails app and cannot find the way to write correctly my line of code for giving as argument a variable ruby to my JS function. I'm trying to implement a countdown feature according to the date of an event.

Here my JS file:

```
let countdown;

const dynamicCountdown = (eventTime) => {
  if (document.querySelector(".timer")) {

    // Set a event date for my tests:
    // const eventTime = new Date();
    // eventTime.setHours(20);
    // eventTime.setMinutes(9);
    // eventTime.setSeconds(0);

    const timeRemaining = Date.parse(eventTime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    
    const hours = Math.floor(timeRemaining / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24);
    const minutes = Math.floor((timeRemaining / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    const seconds = Math.floor((timeRemaining / 1000) % 60);

    if (timeRemaining < 0) {
      clearInterval(countdown);
      return;
    }
    
    const timerDisplay = document.querySelector(".timer");
    const display = `${hours < 10 ? '0' : ''}${hours}:${minutes < 10 ? '0' : ''}${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${seconds}`;
    timerDisplay.textContent = display;
  }
}

setInterval(dynamicCountdown, 1000);

export { dynamicCountdown }
```

And a part of my html.erb show:

```
<h3 class="timer">
  <%= javascript_tag "dynamicCountdown(@event.date_time)" %>
</h3>
```

I tried different way: `javascript_tag`, `<script>` HTML tag... but none is working.

Thanks for your help!

---------------------------- UPDATE -------------------------------

I finally made it! I used a `data-attribut`. Here how I managed it:

I set a data-attribut in my html.erb to access to my value in my js file `<h3 class="timer" data-event-date='<%= @event.date_time %>'>`

And in my html.erb, I retrieve it using those two lines of code:
`const timer = document.querySelector(".timer");`
`const eventDate = timer.dataset.eventDate;`

I hope it could help someone else who wants send data to their js files ;)

Comment: In erb, can't you just "dynamicCountdown(#{@event.date_time})" ?

Comment: It doesn't work, I got an "undefined" message when I console.log(eventTime) and a NaN:NaN:NaN on my timer, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in erb file. I hope it working

```
<script>
  var date_time = "<%= @event.date_time %>";
  
  dynamicCountdown(date_time);
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error message than the code proposed by nghiamt... Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You should move setInterval into script in erb file

```
<script>
  var event_date_time = "<%= @event.date_time %>";

  setInterval(function(){
    dynamicCountdown(event_date_time);
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your way but I get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: dynamicCountdown is not defined" error. Do you know why my erb.html file cannot read properly this JS function?

Comment: @Aelos-74 Did you included your js file into your erb file? You can use `<%= javascript_include_tag('your_js_file.js') %>` to include js file into erb file

Comment: No I didn't, might explain why! If I understood correctly, I should add this <%= javascript_include_tag('dynamic_countdown.js') %> on the top of my html.erb, right? If yes, I tried but I get an asset pipeline error... Do I need to specify a specific path? My js file is in app/javascript/components/dynamic_countdown.js

Comment: yes, you should add `<%= javascript_include_tag('dynamic_countdown.js') %>` on the top of your erb file to include that js file. If not your js code not be included in the erb file so the function dynamicCountdown can not be called.

Comment: What version of Rails do you use?

Comment: Another way to include js file to your erb file is require your js file in application.js file

Comment: Ok thanks for all those details! I tried to add the ```<%= javascript_include_tag('dynamic_countdown.js') %>``` in my erb file but as I told you, it raises an asset pipeline error... I'm using Rails 6.0.3.4

Comment: Here the error "The asset "dynamic_countdown.js" is not present in the asset pipeline."

Comment: In Rails 6, you should user javascript_pack_tag instead of javascript_include_tag

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you so much! I'm quite new in Rails and just discover the asset pipeline today :) Could you tell me how to add my js.file to it please? And I changed ```include``` by ```pack```, now it raises a webpacker error: Webpacker can't find dynamic_countdown.js

Comment: I finally found a simple way to make it: through a ```data-attribut```, I updated my question if you wanna check! Thanks for your help!